# AGPL : license of backend and frontend

Tags: license-recommendation, agpl-3.0, api

I’m a bit confused with AGPL license, so I ask for advice. I read contradictory things on the matter.

I want to make an android app. The backend will use AGPL modified material : [stable diffusion WebUI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui). The backend will probably have some more stuff (like AWS integration code) AND will be usable without the front-end (it’s gonna be an API, a project in itself).
The front-end (android app) will be usable witout THIS specific backend (but will require a backend, IE an API who return images).

So, tell me if any of these are wrong :

1. (Almost sure of that) Everything related to the stable diffusion WebUI must be AGPL.
2. (Quite sure of that) The whole backend (including AWS-related stuff) MUST be AGPL.
3. (No idea if it’s true) The android app itself (wrapping) can be distributed with an other license (for example CC-NC).

Just making sure I get things right!

Comment: How does the front-end communicate with the back-end?  HTTP requests or other well-documented API?  Some interface unique to your app?

Comment: Yes, them will communicate, probably with the AWS API Gateway

Comment: Who will define the API?  You?  Or does the AWS API gateway itself impose a standard for request format and transport?

Comment: AWS API Gateway impose a format (HTTP), but I will be defining the API (what requests will be processed and how).

Comment: I just checked again the AWS API Gateway doc, both HTTP and REST are available. Are you saying that, if my API is easily usable by any user (aka i’m using standard request and I document them), then the backend can be considered as a project in itself ? (therefore allowing my front-end to be CC-NC?)